# How to run syntax on different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble creating a macro that will run my VLOOKUP syntax on two different sheets. I have two sheets (ABC and XYZ).  I want my macro to run two different VLOOKUPs - one on each sheet.

How do I tweak my codes so that it would do this?

```
Sub fillinABC()

Dim ABC As Worksheet
Dim XYZ As Worksheet
Set XYZ = Sheets("XYZ")
Set ABC = Sheets("ABC")

With ABC

    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    MsgBox LastRow
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then 'if cell in A is empty
            Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'[Copy of Manual Recs - List.xlsx]XXX'!C1:C5,5,FALSE)" 'Lookup cell in B in Identifier A:C this is in C1(Column1):C3(Column3) form!!
        End If
    Next

End With

With XYZ

   LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   MsgBox LastRow
   For i = 1 To LastRow
       If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then 'if cell in A is empty
           Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'[Copy of Manual Recs - List.xlsx]XXX'!C2:C5,4,FALSE)" 'Lookup cell in B in Identifier A:C this is in C1(Column1):C3(Column3) form!!
       End If
   Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: OP, see the article about `With...End With Statement` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add a '.' in front of all the Cells calls.  You've used the with block but haven't referenced the worksheets anywhere.  e.g.

```
LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Without referencing the worksheets you're implicitly referencing ActiveSheet.Cells